# Android mp4 seek to is horribly inaccurate

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mp4

I have a mediaplayer and i am trying to play an mp4 video but i only want the audio. so i am using a media player. in there i want to be able to use seek to but for some reason, putting in a seek to is horribly inaccurate. If i put in a function to skip forward 5 seconds. it skips anywhere from 5 seconds backward to 15 seconds forwards. how can it possibly be this inaccurate. is there any way to make a seekto more exact? this doesn't happen with some other video formats.

```
 player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            player.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
            player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    player.setOnCompletionListener(listener);
                    playMusic();
                }
            });
            player.prepareAsync();



 public void playMusic() {
        try {
            if (player != null && !player.isPlaying()) {

                //player.seekTo(1); seeks to begining
                //player.seekTo(311);  skips to 15 seconds
                player.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        player.start();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Perhaps related to this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9135

Comment: What's in your `onCompletionListener()`?

Comment: @akodiakson just a method to to close the player when the track is done